# Can I omit the second "I"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I omit the second "I" in the following sentence:
*"I wanted to have another serving but somehow **I** restrained myself."*

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can omit the second "I." It is grammatically correct to say "I **wanted** [first verb] to have another serving but [conjunction] **restrained** [second verb] myself. You would merely be creating a compound verb.

If you were to keep the second "I," you would need a comma between "serving" and "but" because there would be two complete thoughts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, BreWoodsy.
But, are you sure about the comma "serving" and "but".

Comment: @hni105 SFTLR. Yes, typically in proper grammar, you would need a comma between the two thoughts. Here's some more information on that if you would like to know more: https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/conjunctions_and_commas.htm